# How to remove exp date in php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

in jwt.php in config folder i have commented exp

```
     'iss',
     'iat',
     // 'exp',
     'nbf',
     // 'sub',
     'jti',
 ],
```

Controller:

```
$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload)->get(); //creates jwt token
```

Still i get the expiry date.
i want exp to be removed .

Comment: in jwt config you should set `ttl` to `null`

Answer (score 0):

in jwt config you should set ttl to null –
@geertjanknapen
Thanks